# Union type with object or function not properly checking the function signature

Tags: typescript

Why do I not get a compiler error when I have the `TransitionDefinition` interface defined with:

```
export interface State {
  name: string
}

export type StateResolveFunc = (fsm: string) => State[]

export interface TransitionDefinition {
  from: State | State[] | StateResolveFunc
}
```

and then create an object like:

```
const t0: TransitionDefinition = {
  from: (fsm) => 'startState' // Why do I not get a compiler error?
}
```

I should not be allowed to return a string here!
When I just have the function type and not a union, the compiler complains as expected.

[Typescript example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20interface%20State%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20name%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20type%20StateResolveFunc%20%3D%20(fsm%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20State%5B%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20TransitionDefinition%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20name%3F%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20from%3A%20State%20%7C%20State%5B%5D%20%7C%20StateResolveFunc%0D%0A%20%20to%3A%20StateResolveFunc%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20t0%3A%20TransitionDefinition%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20from%3A%20(fsm)%20%3D%3E%20'startState'%2C%20%2F%2F%20Why%20do%20I%20not%20get%20the%20a%20compiler%20error%3F%0D%0A%20%20to%3A%20(fsm)%20%3D%3E%20'toState'%2C%20%2F%2F%20Works%20as%20expected%3A%20Type%20'string'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20'State%5B%5D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20t1%3A%20TransitionDefinition%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20to%3A%20(fsm)%20%3D%3E%20%5B%7B%20name%3A%20'Start%20State'%20%7D%5D%2C%20%2F%2F%20works%0D%0A%20%20%20%20from%3A%20'startState'%2C%20%2F%2F%20Works%3A%20Type%20'string'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20'State%20%7C%20StateResolveFunc%20%7C%20State%5B%5D'%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)
using typescript 3.1.1

Comment: The cause here is that all functions have a `name` property, so a function (any function) is in fact assignable to `State`. I'm not sure what the best way to work around that is, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the reason behind this behavior is that all functions have a `name` property. Because of that, *any* function will be assignable to `State`.

Since you likely didn't want anything callable to be assigned to `State`, you can ensure that functions are not assignable to it by including an optional `apply` field with type `never`. So something like:

```
interface State {
  name: string;
  apply?: never; // Ensures functions are not assignable to this interface.
}
```

This works because all functions have an `apply` method, but the type of that method isn't `never`, which means it can't be assigned to `State`. This same trick can be used with any of the common function properties, like `call` or `bind`, in place of `apply`.

Anyway, using that trick, your snippet:

```
export interface State {
  name: string;
  apply?: never;
}

export type StateResolveFunc = (fsm: string) => State[]

export interface TransitionDefinition {
  from: State | State[] | StateResolveFunc
}

const t0: TransitionDefinition = {
  from: (fsm) => 'startState' // Now produces an error
}
```

Now creates an error:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'State[]'.